# JSON setting up in php and js

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I know I had already this question asked, but I'm doing something wrong in my code. I know that I need to use JSON, and after going through few pages I understand the theory, but somehow can't make it work here is my code once again (btw I know about my security issues and I'll work on them as soon as I solve my technical issues with JSON):

```
$(document).on('pageinit',function(){
$("#login").click(function(){

username=$("#usr").val();
password=$("#psw").val();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://imes.**********.com/php/login_check.php",
data: "name="+username+"&pwd="+password,
success: function(html){
//in case of success
if(html=='true')
{
var usr = console.log(data.usr);
var psw = console.log(data.psw);
$.cookie('usr', usr);
$.cookie('psw', psw);
$("#login_message").html("Logged in, congratulation.");
$.mobile.changePage("http://imes.**********.com/userpanel.php");
}
//in case of error
else
{
$("#login_message").html("Wrong username or password");
}
},
beforeSend: function() { $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(); }, //Show spinner
complete: function() { $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg() }, //Hide spinner
});
return false;
});
```

And my php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$username = $_POST['name'];
$password = $_POST['pwd'];
include('mysql_connection.php');
mysql_select_db("jzperson_imesUsers", $con);
$res1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM temp_login WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
$num_row = mysql_num_rows($res1);
$res2 = mysql_fetch_array($res1);
if( $num_row == 1 ) {
$arr = array('usr' => $username, 'psw' => $password);
echo json_encode($arr);
echo 'true';
}
else{
echo 'false';
}
?>
```

Comment: Looks like you're echo'ing json encoded data and then a plain string. You need to choose to use one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do (PHP). First setup your response array, default to success `FALSE`.

```
$arr = array('success' => FALSE);
```

Then your condition overwrites if successful:

```
if( $num_row == 1 ) 
{
    $arr = array('success' => TRUE, 'usr' => $username, 'psw' => $password);
}
```

Finally at the end of the script return the result as JSON encoded data.

```
echo json_encode($arr);
exit();
```

I would make the following change to your jQuery also:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://imes.**********.com/php/login_check.php",
    data: "name="+username+"&pwd="+password,
    dataType: 'json', // let's it know the response will be JSON formatted
    success: function(json){
        if (json.success === true){
            // do whatever you want here
        }
});
```

A bit of advice though: you should never pass a user's password to the front-end.
There is no need for it, ever.

Answer (score 1):

Your out put is not valid json, echoing a true or false after the json will cause it to be invalid. You have to insert the success message into the json data.

```
if( $num_row == 1 ) {
    $arr = array('usr' => $username, 'psw' => $password);
    echo json_encode(array('data'=>$arr, 'success'=>true);
    //echo 'true';
}
else{
    echo json_encode(array('success'=>false);
}
```

then check in your ajax success callback

```
success: function(json){
//in case of success
if(json.success){
    var usr = json.data.usr;
    ...
}
else{
    ...
}
```

Also you should pass your parameters to data as an object so it will be properly encoded.

```
data: {"name":username,"pwd":password},
```

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, JSON is basically the right-hande-side of a variable definition in JS:

```
var myvar = ....;
            ^^^^---- basically JSON
```

Since you're doing

```
echo json_encode($var);
echo 'true';
```

in your PHP code, consider how it'll look from the client side:

```
var myvar = 'somestring'true;
                        ^^^^---syntax error
```

if you're outputting JSON for consumption by an AJAX call in your JS code, then the JSON text is the **ONLY** thing that can be output by the server as its response. Anything else will simply mangle the json string somehow, and make it invalid.